# Set default style in Java 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In JavaFX 8 application I'm using `setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);` to set the default skin style. But in Netbeans I get error:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable STYLESHEET_CASPIAN
  location: class MainApp
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

In order to remove the warning in Netbeans I tried tried this:

```
String STYLESHEET_CASPIAN = null;

setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);
```

But it's not correct. How I can remove the warning message?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STYLESHEET_CASPIAN` was introduced in FX8 (jdk8). If you intent to use FX2.x you don't need to change user agent stylesheet (caspian is only and default).

If your project compiles, but NB shows warning it's NetBeans issue. Most probably you had FX2.x in you project previously and NB remembered it. Try to change platform in project options back and forth to reset NB cache.

Comment: Bad news. I added `setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);` but I still get warning message. Maybe the problem is caused by Netbeans?

Comment: Yes `import javafx.application.Application;`

Comment: It should work.  You don't even need the 'Application.' in front of the constant.  Try a clean and build.

Comment: Well, I can compile the code and run it but I see warning message into Netbeans. It seems that the problem is in Netbeans.

Comment: oh, it actually is a NetBeans issue, see updated answer.